# QT 4.7.4 : need a signal when qsplitter is collapsed

Tags: qt

I am somewhat new to qt and working on an already written code.
I am trying to do something whenever a specific widget in  my Qsplitter is collapsed.
for this I need a signal from qsplitter or qsplitterhandle.

Answer (score 3):

A `QSplitter` will emit the signal [splitterMoved(int pos, int index)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsplitter.html#splitterMoved) when it is resized. You should be able to identify the splitter you are interested in with `index` and then look at the value of `pos` to determine if it is collapsed.